# Unable to attach AddRemoveListener to UIViewRoot because it is null/ The view can not be restored errors with jsf2.0 and openam

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, openam

I have an JSF 2.1 application, developed using primefaces 3.4, working fine.The problem appears when I add agent filter to my glassfish 3.1 server.
I have an "Unable to attach AddRemoveListener to UIViewRoot because it is null" error when I click a button in glassfish console.
Does somebody get a similar problem?

web.xml

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Agent</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Agent</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Errors in Glassfish console:

```
ATTENTION: Unable to attach AddRemoveListener to UIViewRoot because it is null
ATTENTION: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:439)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:573)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:115)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.sbs.servlets.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentBaseFilter.allowRequestToContinue(AmAgentBaseFilter.java:127)
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentBaseFilter.doFilter(AmAgentBaseFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

In the browser

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: AmAgentFilter: An exception has occured
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: viewId:/clients.xhtml - La vue «/clients.xhtml» n?a pas pu être restaurée.
root cause

javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/clients.xhtml - View "/ clients.xhtml" could not be restored.
```

I notice that,if the agent filter is like this

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>Agent</filter-name>
        <filter-class> com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentFilter </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Agent</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

(I remove   `<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>` ); I don't have this error anymore. Is the application still protected with this OpenAm Filter configuration?

Comment: Please post relevant part of changes to web.xml due to Agent Filter addition and error log for others to look at.

Comment: Edited with web.xml, glassfish console errors.I have two more filters in the app:one for no-caching the data and the second is primefaces filter for upload

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this same error (`WARNING: Unable to attach AddRemoveListener to UIViewRoot because it is null`) in a few rare cases while debugging.  The particulars were that I had a browser window open from a previous debugging run which was attempting an ajax callback on a timer.  I had recompiled the app in the interim (with Netbeans) and re-run it.  Every time the browser with the non-current tab issued the ajax call I saw this warning.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!This issue happened because of `primefaces css &js` ,and other `css and js` files not present in `"NOT ENFORCED URI"`.
As resources as served through javax.faces.resource, I had to add in the "NOT ENFORCED URI"

```
/<webappcontext>/javax.faces.resource/*?*
```

Comment: Would you please edit this answer with more detail?  Which file exactly did you change, etc. - Thank you :)

Comment: I did not changea file in Netbeans. With OpenAM, you have to declare NOT ENFORCED URI.This will permit the OpenAm Policy Agent to allow access to that URI. In my case, I permitted /<webappcontext>/resources/css/theme.css for example.When I clicked on a button, I had that error. I checked and see in the policy Agent log that /<webappcontext>/javax.faces.resource/afile.css was not allowed.

Comment: I'm not using OpenAM so I can't use this but as I described my path to the problem is a bit different anyway. Thank you for your reply!